# If I create a localhost database, who can access it?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, sql, tableview

Basically just need "localhost" explained.  If I build a database in Xampp that receives data from text fields in an iOS app, and then loads that data into a tableview, will everyone that uses my app be able to load the data on their phone? Or does it depend on user location?

Comment: LocalHost means the local computer's hosted services. It should only be used for development and testing since it isn't exposed outside your computer. Here's the first Google result https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Answer (score 0):

So you are using something like, remote SQL, or web services, in that if your processing script, for eg. PHP / ASP resides on the same server where your database is, then you can specify

> URL= localhost 
>  data base name= your DB name 
> user name= your DB
>   Username 
> password= your DB Password

So if your code is properly working, then users can see details on their mobile phones irrespective of their geographic location.

in case if you are using remote SQL, means if your processing script and database are at different location, then instead of localhost, you need to write the URL provided by your database provider.